# Regex for extract chars from a 2 space separated columns

Tags: regex

I need a regex expression to parse a line.
The number of spaces separating the data are 2 or more and the column value can be one word or words separated by 1 space.
e.g
Input:
`01   Active/Active      VXSM_T1E1         MAJOR      NA          NO REDUNDANCY`
So, the output for this one should be:
`01`
`Active/Active`
`VXSM_T1E1`
`MAJOR`
`NA`
`NO REDUNDANCY`

Input:
`01   Active/Active      VXSM_T1E1         MAJOR NEXT      NA          NO REDUNDANCY ELEMENT`
So, the output for this one should be:
`01`
`Active/Active`
`VXSM_T1E1`
`MAJOR NEXT`
`NA`
`NO REDUNDANCY ELEMENT`

I started with: (\S+\s\s)|(\S+\s)+
but could not solve all my issues

Comment: It's possible that your programming language (actually if you're coding) has a `split` function which corresponds to Regular Expressions. Use it with this regex `\s{2,}`

Comment: where are you struggeling? what did you try? I mean I can give you a regex, but I am not sure this is helping you in the long run... nevertheless a hint: `\s` matches one space character; @revo due to your example I put in `\s\s+`

Comment: What you've tried so far. Please post your inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt `(\S+\s\s)|(\S+\s)+` matches one of the two cases either one or more characters followed by two spaces or one or more groups of one or more characters followed by a single space.

If you look at your requirements, you need to combine those two as a single choice.  You want the whole group to be followed by two spaces, and you want your group to contain single spaces.

`(\S+\s)*\S+(\s\s|$)` matches zero or more groups of characters followed by a single space, folowed by one or more characters, followed by either two spaces or the end line.

This includes trailing spaces in your capture.  If that is unwanted the final capturing group should be a lookahead.

Comment: My approach would have been: `(.*?)(\s\s+|$)`

Comment: @futu My philosophy is to always have my regexp describe what I am looking for as closely as I am able.  Relying on reluctant matching in this case would work, but requirements change, and reluctant matching could break easily.  In this case you could make the case that it's easier to see that your code avoids catastrophic backtracking.